# HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Error on specific devices?

Tags: java, android, json, http

So when I'm downloading the txt file of my google sheet document I get this HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily error. This only happens on my device which has android 4.1.2.

It works fine on my emulator and have tested it without any problems on a newer device (android 6.0).

Here is the error:

```
D/Result: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
              Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
              Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
              Pragma: no-cache
              Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
              Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2016 07:45:42 GMT
              Location: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T8v8xI_NEqvTlMqknR2_ZqgmPSdqrPphkDVwa6jM_6E/gviz/tq
              P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
              P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
              Content-Encoding: gzip
              X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
              X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
              Server: GSE
              Set-Cookie: NID=88=AonSZlvYLa0ZXd-IFsyUeLLIVL8D0AR62cZV6t7J-glcZFVZwcJRZZyMtC2Tg1pYqHN0jtCskzHVOsqCpLXi9aDdnqBV34DrTmnSErpZQc75zXH0w-qiJ8WWie3dn5UK;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 12-Apr-2017 07:45:42 GMT;HttpOnly
              Set-Cookie: NID=88=k2RCOAv_u7aZ4MOMqF_wP7bQ0bFpbxDiLZcCE9628HRhUR-q941P34h91TAmbct_gGR5F_JDKHxDeQVl8G8Nz-zlEab8G0vHD-3uu58Y-GKWCF_iTIMCasTBrmIMoKWJ;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 12-Apr-2017 07:45:42 GMT;HttpOnly
              Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34,33,32"
              Transfer-Encoding: chunked

              00000001

              00000001
              ?
              00000001

              00000001
              ??
              00000001
              ??
              001
              ??
              e3
              ????????m?KO?0?????g)??Bn????RB?`!?E???u? <~=???\V;;?[R???R???XE?Zς#&?mo????CB?/?i????k??]?mF?>??^G?K???&L
              ???]??G?wH??Q???K?'w2.?F??7Y?s'??8,?j^}?jf6??tno?W3??#7v??S???/??nIa????
              Τ??@??????'~???zJ?????
              0
```

Also here is when the app shuts down

```
 String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I was downloading 2 sheets. Problem was that I had deleted one of them and I didin't remember. The crash would happen only on older versions of android and that's why I didin't noticed it earlier and didin't expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

302 is not an error. 
It is a way of redirecting. From what I see, your file is getting downloaded. Some clients do follow redirects and some don't (I do not know the defaults on Android, but assume they do).

Can you share the URL you are trying to get?

See more details about 302:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: Here is the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X5oGmyH4qbPQcGroR2RhwMX_RkoVYcmev4fLu9Rs9Ig/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe in your code you are trying to access http instead of https?

Also, you should try forcing the client to follow redirects.

Comment: Well I just found out the problem. I was downloading from 2 links. Problem was I had deleted one of the sheets and I had completly forgotten. I don't know why the error happened on my old device only. But now it got fixed! Thanks for making me go check out my sheets again LOL xD